# Xming not working with Cygwin

Tags: cygwin, xming

I have two Windows 10 machines with Cygwin + Xming, one of them works fine, but I can't get the other one to work, if I try to start ddd for instance, I get:

> Error: Can't open display:

If I manually set $DISPLAY it works, but X11 forwarding from remote hosts doesn't

The second machine works flawlessy, $DISPLAY is automatically set and X11 forwarding works.

**PuTTY is NOT involved in this setup**

Xming is running in both machines in localhost:0.0

I've been trying for a while and I might've forgot to check something, but I can't get it to work :(

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: If X11 Forwarding isn’t working, run `ssh` in a reasonably verbose mode (`-vvv`). This will print a lot of stuff. Read it all.

Comment: It's not just X11 Forwarding, I can't run local X11 applications (ddd is mentioned as example)

Comment: That’s just because `$DISPLAY` isn’t set. To be expected of course, seeing how there’s no integration whatsoever between Xming and Cygwin.

Comment: On the other machine $DISPLAY is set on startup and X11 forwarding works

That indicates there's some integration between Xming and Cygwin

Comment: You most likely added it to some startup file and forgot about it.

Comment: That's what I thought initially. I checked for it, and there are no matches

Plus, as said, if I set DISPLAY and do ssh forwarding it doesn't work, but with the other machine it is set and x11 forwarding works, and DISPLAY isn't set up nowhere within the startup files, which means that SOMETHING is setting it up and also making X11 forwarding work in the process